# UITableView reuse cells (stop duplicating)

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  { 
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"simpleTable";
     profileCellViewController *cell = [self.myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"simpleTable" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0]; 
        }
  //loading data
   ...
   ...
   ...

     cell.name.text     = name;
     cell.time.text = time;
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
     return cell;
  }
```

I know the problem is in the if (cell==nil) part
but really don't know hoe I can solve this...
every time im back to this viewcontroller tab the cells duplicated

Comment: Probably irrelevant to your problem but that's a pretty bad place to load data, don't you think?

Comment: im just reading there all the relevant name to the cell's labels from the database

Comment: Have you put the correct reuse identifier for the cell in the nib file?

Comment: as Desdenova said, do a LoadData method that returns an array or dictionary, then use that array as datasource for your taable. That way, what you have to do when you consider necessary, call LoadData followed by [tableview reloaddata]

Comment: im doing this already Im just getting the name from Parse its not related to the duplicate cells problem I'm having because the problem is in the IF statement and it happen the same for another table not loading the data inside this method..

Comment: @Abizern Yes, I think if it wasn't it wouldn't work at all

Comment: Cells are just empty, structured containers.  If they appear to be duplicated it's because of the data being put into them.  Is there any other code where you update cell contents?  If not, I suggest showing how you select the `name` and `time` to display.

Comment: what do you mean? does it matter how I put the content?